# Filling in a symmetric 2D array

Tags: python

I have this code, but I don't know how can I make it looks like a python code and not a c-like code:

```
n=10

a = [[0 for row in xrange(n)]for col in range(n) ]
for i in xrange(n):
    a[i][0] = 1
    a[0][i] = 1


for i in xrange(1,n):
    for j in xrange(1,n):
        a[i][j] = a[i-1][j] + a[i][j-1]
```

Comment: ..Looks like python to me >_>

Comment: he probably means `more pythonic`

Comment: you could use `[0]*n` with immutable types such as `int`, otherwise the code is fine. Without knowing where this code is used it is unclear whether you need to use `numpy` arrays, `comb(i+j, j, 1)` or something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
n = 10

a = [[1 if i==0 or j==0 else 0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]

for i,j in product(range(1, n), repeat=2):
         a[i][j] = a[i-1][j] + a[i][j-1]
```

---

You could also generate `a` like this:

```
a = [[1 - (i > 0 < j) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be generating a grid of binomial coefficients.

Look how this is done with [Scipy](http://www.scipy.org/):

```
>>> from scipy import *
>>> n = 10
>>> fromfunction(lambda i,j: comb(i+j, j), shape=(n,n))
array([[  1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00,   1.00e+00],
       [  1.00e+00,   2.00e+00,   3.00e+00,   4.00e+00,   5.00e+00,   6.00e+00,   7.00e+00,   8.00e+00,   9.00e+00,   1.00e+01],
       [  1.00e+00,   3.00e+00,   6.00e+00,   1.00e+01,   1.50e+01,   2.10e+01,   2.80e+01,   3.60e+01,   4.50e+01,   5.50e+01],
       [  1.00e+00,   4.00e+00,   1.00e+01,   2.00e+01,   3.50e+01,   5.60e+01,   8.40e+01,   1.20e+02,   1.65e+02,   2.20e+02],
       [  1.00e+00,   5.00e+00,   1.50e+01,   3.50e+01,   7.00e+01,   1.26e+02,   2.10e+02,   3.30e+02,   4.95e+02,   7.15e+02],
       [  1.00e+00,   6.00e+00,   2.10e+01,   5.60e+01,   1.26e+02,   2.52e+02,   4.62e+02,   7.92e+02,   1.29e+03,   2.00e+03],
       [  1.00e+00,   7.00e+00,   2.80e+01,   8.40e+01,   2.10e+02,   4.62e+02,   9.24e+02,   1.72e+03,   3.00e+03,   5.01e+03],
       [  1.00e+00,   8.00e+00,   3.60e+01,   1.20e+02,   3.30e+02,   7.92e+02,   1.72e+03,   3.43e+03,   6.43e+03,   1.14e+04],
       [  1.00e+00,   9.00e+00,   4.50e+01,   1.65e+02,   4.95e+02,   1.29e+03,   3.00e+03,   6.43e+03,   1.29e+04,   2.43e+04],
       [  1.00e+00,   1.00e+01,   5.50e+01,   2.20e+02,   7.15e+02,   2.00e+03,   5.00e+03,   1.14e+04,   2.43e+04,   4.86e+04]])
```

This is also much faster than iterating over each element indexes with `for` loops.

---

Simple is better than complex. [PEP20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: is there a way to keep numbers as `ints` and `longs`?

Comment: Argh, I was writing a very similar answer and then you answer came up. Anyways +1 :).

Comment: @Doboy, yes, just wrap the result in `array(..., dtype=int)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I am and will be using wildcard imports in interactive sessions regardless of anyone's dreaded namespace pollution concerns. It's convenient. I will almost certainly consider using qualified imports in "big" python code, and on a case-by-case basis in small scripts. But in REPL — `from module import *` only, period.

Comment: @ulidtko: sure, you can use whatever you like in your REPL, but SO is not an interactive console. Think about readers of your answer. Don't spread bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

maybe using dictionaries would be cleaner? not sure though..

```
a = {}
for i in xrange(n):
    a[i, 0] = a[0, i] = 1

for i in xrange(1, n):
    for j in xrange(1, n):
        a[i, j] = a[i-1, j] + a[i, j-1]
```

or you can just write a function for this and letting the recursion figure things out.

```
@memoize
def a(i, j):
     if i == 0 or j == 0:
           return 1
     else:
           return a(i-1, j) + a(i, j-1)
```

Comment: spaces immediately inside `()`? ow my eyes hurt

Comment: it was a convention at a place that i used to work at, sorry.

Comment: Close :) can you take out the spaces around the `-` too?

Comment: Ah, the balance has been restored :)

Comment: @gnibbler Spaces around operators is PEP8.

Comment: `a = lambda i,j: a(i-1, j) + a(i, j-1) if i and j else 1`

Comment: most people can write one liners, but is it more `pythonic` in this case? Iono, but they are definitely less readable..

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me, except that since you appear to be working with a 2D array, maybe [numpy](https://numpy.org/) would be useful.

Then you could write e.g.

```
a = numpy.zeros((n,n))
a[0,:] = 1
a[:,0] = 1
```

Comment: I'm out of votes today; so have my virtual **+1**. By the way, numerical `for` loops in Python are very slow, I'd suggest that the best answer would use vectorization techniques and Numpy broadcasting.